# prove that $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{2}-x+1}{x+1}=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Please check my proof

Let $\epsilon >0$ and $\delta >0$

$$0<x<\delta \rightarrow \frac{x^{2}-x+1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{2}<\epsilon $$

$$\frac{2x^{2}-2x+2-x+1}{2x+2}<\epsilon $$
$$\frac{2x^{2}-3x+1}{2x+2}<\epsilon $$
since   $\frac{2x^2-3x+1}{2x+2} <\frac{2x^{2}-3x+2}{2}$

then $\frac{2x^{2}-3x+1}{2}< \epsilon $

$2x^{2}-3x+1<2\epsilon $
choose $2\epsilon =\delta $

then $\frac{2x^{2}-3x+1}{2}<\frac{2\epsilon }{2}=\epsilon $

by transitivity of inequality

$\frac{2x^{2}-3x+1}{2x+2}<\epsilon $

Comment: it should be $\frac{2x^{2}-2x+2-x-1}{2x+2}<\epsilon$

Comment: Could work out more easily if you first wrote it as $\frac{x^2-x+1}{x+1}=x-2+\frac{3}{x+1}\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an error in the second line of the development.

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^2-x+1}{x+1}-\frac12\right|&=\left|\frac{2x^2-3x+1}{2(x+1)}\right|\\\\
&=\left|\frac{(2x-1)(x-1)}{2(x+1)}\right|
\end{align}$$

Now, bound $|x-1|$ by something somewhat arbitrary such as $0<x<2$.  Then $1<x+1<3$ and $-1<2x-1<3$ so that $\frac{|2x-1|}{2(x+1)}<\frac32$ and for $|x-1|<1$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^2-x+1}{x+1}-\frac12\right|&=\frac32 |x-1|\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|x-1|<\delta=\min\left(1,\frac{2}{3}\epsilon\right)$.  And we are done!

Answer (score 0):

This function is defined at continuous at x = 1.

(It would be a different problem is we were looking for the limit as x approaches -1)

Unless your professor is demanding epsilon-delta proofs for the practice, you know that the limit of a defined continuous f as x approaches 1 is 
$f(1) = \frac{1^2 - 1 + 1}{1 + 1} = \frac{1}{2}$

(It is OK to do epsilon-delta proofs for practice if the professor thinks you need more practice; just not necessary here.)